# Python 2.7 VSCODE doesn't get the correct length of input string

Tags: python, python-2.7, visual-studio-code

in my class we are studying python 2.7. I am using vscode to test the exercises.

> exercise 1: read user input and print the length. If the user write
>   exit the program finish.

My code is follow:

```
myexit=False
while (myexit!=True):
    #read user input
    txt=raw_input("write a string or write exit to go out: ")
    #print the user input string
    print txt
    if (str(txt)=='exit'):
        myexit=True#exit from while
    else:
        print len(txt) #print the string length
print "finish"
```

when i **test** the code **i get always the length of the string +1**

> example: if i write foo the output is 4 and no 3. When i write exit i
>   don't go out from the while and the output is 5.

Where i wrong ?

I have missed a module?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I tried same code in Python 2.7 and also in Python 3.7 where raw_input() was renamed to input() and it works without any problem.

Comment: I've not been able to repro this in REPL.  but try using `print repr(text)` to see what exactly is in the string

Comment: Thanks for your reply guys, @Doon i have tried print repr(txt) and i get: example i write my and in output i get  my\r. why?

Comment: Hmm `\r` is a carriage return. What operating system are you running on? and are you running the file via VScode, or via CLI/Termina/CMD.  Short answer is that I am guessing you are using Windows.`\r\n` is standard windows EOL, whereas unix uses`\n`. raw_input is stripping the the newline, but the carriage return., and I am not sure why

Comment: my SO is win10 and i use vscode to test the code and when i click F5 open the debug where i write in the terminal

Comment: another option would be to use `rstrip()` to remove the \r from  the end of the line.

Comment: Thank you very much @Doon if you write the answer i vote up you...you are very polite...I solved the problem with txt.rstrip()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure exactly why this is happening, and I don't have access to a windows machine to test/verify but based on the comments above, it appears that on the version of python you are using that `raw_input` is only stripping the newline(`\n`) and not the carriage return(`\r`).  Windows uses `\r\n` while unix uses `\n`.  When raw input returns the `\r` is still on the string, hence the extra char.  A useful debugging technique at the cli is to use the function `repr()` on the value to see exactly how it is represented. This is helpful to locate any stray control or invisible chars in strings.

The function `rstrip()` will remove all whitespace from the right side of the string, which in this case should safely remove the stray `\r`. It should also be safe if this code is running on a *nix like system as `rstrip()` will only remove the whitespace if it is present.  You can also specify a set of char to strip, so if you would would like to be pedantic, you could use `rstrip("\r")`.

```
txt=raw_input("write a string or write exit to go out: ").rstrip("\r")
```

Should fix the issue while still maintaining compatibility on different versions.